# How to decide the boundary line between being polite and being firm?

Tags: air-travel

I was returning home via a domestic flight this week. Now, I am a vegetarian and absolutely can't consume non-vegetarian food (it's a matter of belief).

During the flight, I received non-vegetarian meal despite having told the flight hostess that i wanted a vegetarian one.
I realise it might not seem like a big deal, but I felt the need to file a small complaint in the office concerned. At the same time my gut feeling told me i was simply over-reacting to a small incident and should just consider it as their small mistake. I did end up filing a complaint after the flight.

I'm not sure if I made the right decision now.
Was I wrong in what I did? I do realise they have a lot of work on their hands and this might come across as being rude, but at the same time i think that they need to act more responsibly.

Comment: This is more about etiquette than about travel. The answer would be the same if you had received a non-vegetarian meal at a local restaurant.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really travel related.

Comment: One solution in the future is to specifically request a vegetarian meal from the airlines BEFORE the flight. This is often called a "special meal" and is held separately. If they had run out of vegetarian meals before they got to you, there's not much a flight attendant can do.